# Page only accessible via joomla iframe and not in browser

Tags: php, redirect, iframe, joomla

I got a Joomla iframe which displays a webbased application. Now I want to prevent people from browsing to the pages that I use like: http://www.mywebsite.com/webapplicationname/login.php

When browsing to there they should automaticly be redirected to http://www.mywebsite.com and login in the iframe.

So I want to prevent people from browsing to my webapplication and only make it accessible via the iframe. Is there any way that I can do that? Or at least prevent people from accessing the login page via the browser instead of the iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the javascript code that checks if a page is loaded inside an iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if (top === self) { not in a frame } else { in a frame }</script>
```

You can then put the code to open the iframe inside the `else`

Comment: So I've just got to display the html if the page is loaded in a iframe and if not redirect it to the page that contains the iframe. But javascript can be disabled so its not the perfect solution for me yet.. It is if there is no other way.

Comment: I think there isn't another option. To check if a page is loaded inside an iframe, code needs to be executed on your computer (using javascript). I should try to avoid using an iframe, and use a div instead.

Comment: Well thats a bit the problem. It needs to be seperated from Joomla, so I can't include divs and such in there because that way it would depend on Joomla. But thanks for the help.